# Video with a BlobURL src doesn't play on iOS 10.3

Tags: javascript, ios, video, bloburls

Preload video as `Blob`, and then use `createObjectURL()` to create a BlobURL. The video plays on all OSs/browsers, but on iOS 10.3 got rejected when trying to play (promise) with the message:

`NotSupportedError (DOM Exception 9): The operation is not supported.`

If switch the `<video>` src to a normal video url, it plays normally.

The code to get the blob url:

```
fetch(videoURL)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(window.URL.createObjectURL)
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: Which one are you using safari browser? or WKWebview?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina safari browser, but I would assume WKWebview behaves the same since it's the same in iOS chrome. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @lassemt nope..